# Entity Framework Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm currently using EF 4.0. My objective is to delete a child collection and add new ones to same parent.

```
 public void AddKids(int parentId, Kids newKids)
 {
    using (ModelContainer context = new ModelContainer(connectionString))
    {
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            var query = from Parent _parent in context.Parents
                        where _parent.ParentId == parentId select _parent;

            Parent parent = query.Single();
            while (parent.Kids.Any())
            {
                context.Kids.DeleteObject(parent.Kids.First());
            }

            if (newKids != null)
            {
                foreach (Kid _kid in newKids)
                {
                    parent.Kids.Add(new Kid
                    {
                        Age = _kid.Age,
                        Height = _kid.Height
                    });
                }
            }
            scope.Complete();
        }
        context.SaveChanges(); //Error happens here
    }
}
```

The error is as from the title: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @JustinNiessner: Thank you, I editted my question.

Comment: Now I'm also wondering where parent is defined.

Comment: You open a new context yet you modify an old cached? instance of parent. I quess there is your problem. You should open the context, retrieve the parent and modify that.

Comment: I have editted my question once more. Thank you guys.

Comment: I tried setting a complete mock copy of this up. It works fine for me :/.

Comment: Btw. you can remove your `TransactionScope` because it is not used at all.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka: Thanks for pointing that out, I need to move context.SaveChanges(); above scope.Complete();

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You are seeing this because you delete objects from a collection that currently has active operations on. More specifically you are updating the Kids collection and then executing the Any() operator on it in the while loop. This is not a supported operation when working with IEnumerable instances. What I can advice you to do is rewrite your while as this:

```
parent.Kids.ToList().ForEach(r => context.Kids.DeleteObject(r));
```

Comment: I have tried your method as well with same error. After a couple of hours digging, it turned out the posted codes work fine. I found out my issue with modifying the "Kids" collection later on in the process. Thank you for helping.

Comment: I am happy I have helped. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Perfect! helped me too :D

Comment: Worth mentioning, perhaps, that this is because EF (afaik) lazy-loads the entities when you keep them in `IEnumerable`, and deleting entities from a group that you haven't actually pulled from the database puts you into a, how do you say, *temporal paradox*. `ToList` forces the pull to happen immediately (eagerly loads?) . Now you have real entities to push around. ;^)

Comment: I experienced the same error using EF ~6. I have two entities that have the exact same properties and data types. I am using tasks which means the deletion of these two entities are happening at the same time. One of the two entities encounters this error while the other one does not. 

Now, if I trigger the deletion synchronously I do not get an error. Maybe someone can shed light?

Comment: Same issue but due to using FindAsync it seems, despite running checks against the entity apparently retrieved. Removing the Async aspect of the entity fetch resolved the issue.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem/error. The solution of ruffin worked.

this crashes :

```
var objectsToRemove = employee.Contracts.Where(m => ...);
objectsToRemove.ForEach(m => _context.Contracts.Remove(m));
```

this worked for me :

```
var objectsToRemove = employee.Contracts.Where(m => ...).ToList();
objectsToRemove.ForEach(m => _context.Contracts.Remove(m));
```

Comment: No need to confirm answers here. If they help you, please upvote, no need to repeat.